# Advanced markings in ConTeXt Mk IV

Tags: context, context-mkiv

Is there a way to somehow get all markings defined on one page (writing some `lua` code for example) ? The idea is to collect marks related to all titles (say sections and subsections for example) on one give page and process these to display them in the page header. As far as I know the `\getmarking` command allows to get first and last markings only.

Comment: That is not possible.  First of all the markings are implemented as some kind of stack, i.e. only the relevant values are kept, others are throw away.  Second, this stack is nicely encapsulated in the corresponding Lua code, i.e. no access from outside the core file is possible.  That means you would have to intercept markings on the macro level (`\strc_markings_set`) and trace page breaks yourself (and/or hook into `\strc_markings_synchronize`).

Comment: In the end I could manage implement this using lua code using data ConTeXt maintains (namely structures.sections and structures.lists.ordered).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by OP but no details given.